# Launch remote process for automated test using Kiwi tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Is it possible to have a kiwi-tcms test case launch an executable on a remote server in order to execute the test case and if so how could that be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - NO!

Long answer:

what you are looking for is some kind of test runner or CI system - that will connect to a remote computer (or use an API directly) and launch automated test cases based on some parameters.

This brings up so many questions I can't even list all of them here but some of the most important ones:

- who/where we store authentication credentials
- how are progress and results monitored and reported
- when are tests scheduled ? What kind of triggers are supported/desired ?

Kiwi TCMS takes a different approach when dealing with automated tests. You can schedule your tests in any way you like and then report the execution results back to Kiwi TCMS.

We are working on plugins for popular test runners, like JUnit, Python Nose, etc, that will automatically discover the result and name of your automated test cases and report them back to Kiwi TCMS.

If you do need a specific plugin/framework please open a request on GitHub and our team will take it into consideration.

Edit: upvote, comment & follow this feature request at https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/914

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar: run automation on remote systems and report results back to Kiwi. I put together several components to get the entire system working. Here's what worked for me:

- Jenkins to initiate test runs and manage remote machines
- A Python script to create test runs against a test plan and write out a custom test run manifest, which is...
- Passed to the automation system (.NET/C#) via more scripts to make sure the remote machine is configured correctly
- Automation output is directly consumed by Jenkins to report test results for the build/job as well as consumed by another Python script that pushes results back to Kiwi

The automation system knows how to interpret the test run manifest and map test cases to test methods implementing the test. It's important to include the Kiwi caserunid throughout the pipeline so the result is associated with the correct Kiwi entry.

Comment: Currently we use Rational Quality Manager as our tcms but we've been looking into the possibility of open source alternatives. RQM ships with adapter software that runs on the machines which execute the automated tests. The RQM server interfaces with these remote adapters to launch a process on the remote machine to execute the test, and the return value of the process is used to indicate the test pass status for recording by RQM. We can schedule test cases for immediate or future execution from the RQM web interface.

Answer (score 1):

please open feature requests on GitHub if you'd like to get test runner adapters (essentially plugins) for Kiwi TCMS. GitHub is the only place where we can track who needs what and prioritize!