# Is it possible to run test cases created with selenium and cucumber in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, execution, kiwi-tcms

I am new to Kiwi TCMS. I have some questions which I'm confused about.

Firstly, is it possible to install Kiwi in Windows since the documentation https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/set_dev_env.html#install-python-3 is for Linux based operating systems.

Also, I do not have any information on - if i can use Kiwi to execute test cases created with Cucumber and Selenium Web Driver.

My idea is to upload the jar file in Kiwi and continue with the execution.

If yes, how can I upload and then execute the test cases?

I have already created an account in Kiwi but I cant understand how should I execute/upload my code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, is it possible to install Kiwi in Windows

Yes. But it's not officially supported / endorsed and there could be [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299729/kiwi-tcms-windows-installation-and-configuration-without-docker) or [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254166/solved-kiwi-tcms-under-docker-windows-issues) if you are unfamiliar with docker / unix.

> Also, I do not have any information on - if i can use Kiwi to execute test cases created with Cucumber and Selenium Web Driver.

No. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738451/launch-remote-process-for-automated-test-using-kiwi-tcms). But there is an open issue on GitHub for this functionality - see https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/914 .

Answer (score -2):

To execute test cases created from  cucumber + selenium web-driver can use Jenkins as test execution environment. It is open source and gives you even the possibility to visualize reports from cucumber